# Converting a location such as "Buffalo, New York" to Latitude and Longitude using the Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-maps

Ok, I'm using the Google Maps API and I need to convert my users location they enter, convert it to Latitude/Longitude using the API. So far, I just have some PHP, But i'm not sure how to implement this into the javascript, etc.

```
    <?php

$coords = toCoordinates("88 Main St. New York New York USA");

function toCoordinates($address)
{
    $bad = array(
        " " => "+",
        "," => "",
        "?" => "",
        "&" => "",
        "=" => ""
    );
    $address = str_replace(array_keys($bad), array_values($bad), $address);
    $data = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents("http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?output=xml&q={$address}"));
    $coordinates = explode(",", $data->Response->Placemark->Point->coordinates);
    return array(
        "latitude" => $coordinates[0],
        "longitude" => $coordinates[1]
    );
}
?>
```

Thank you!

Comment: plz tell us what error did you get??

Answer (score 2):

```
first you have to create the xml and after that pass the xml to the javascript stated below



    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<markers>
    <marker Company_Name="Company Name" address="Address" lat="39.74259" lng="-104.98359" type="comp"/>
    <marker Company_Name="Company Name" address="Address" lat="39.6823891" lng="-104.9373677" type="comp"/>

</markers>





<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

var customIcons = {

comp: {
icon: 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=<?php echo $allcompanyaddress[8];?>|FF0000|000000',
shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
},

};

function myload() {
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $info['latitude']; ?>,  <?php echo $info['longitude'];?>),
zoom: 10,
mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
});
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

// Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
// downloadUrl("<?php echo base_url();?>user_jobplacement/googlemap_record/'", function(data) {
downloadUrl("URL of your XML", function(data) {
var xml = data.responseXML;
var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
var name = markers[i].getAttribute("Company_Name");
var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
var broker = markers[i].getAttribute("broker");
var phone  = markers[i].getAttribute("phone");
var paid   = markers[i].getAttribute("paid");

  var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;

var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
map: map,
position: point,
icon: icon.icon,
shadow: icon.shadow
});
bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
}
});
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
infoWindow.setContent(html);
infoWindow.open(map, marker);
});
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
new XMLHttpRequest;

request.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (request.readyState == 4) {
request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
callback(request, request.status);
}
};

request.open('GET', url, true);
request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}
window.onload = myload;
//]]>
</script>

<div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 338px"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using JQuery for that? You simply need to use GET with parameters(address in your case) like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.get(
                "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=88 Main St. New York New York USA&sensor=true",
                function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
        );
    });
    </script>
</head>
</html>
```

In return you get all the content in data variable(object) from which you can simply extract the latitude and longitude. For your case change the address in URL to value entered by user.